# Rails database changing boolean into true

Tags: postgresql, devise, admin, postgresql-9.1, ruby-on-rails-4.2

Hi i am currently using Devise with a database name user.

now i got another parameter in the database which is an admin and then its type is Boolean.

so this is my concern how can i make it true , when i made the user so its currently not true, its default is false right , so now i want to turn on the admin parameters into true.

I know i need to use the console but how can i do it?
also before i forget i am also using postgresql
i am a bit new here so i dont know how to edit it as i was before using php, and using phpmyadmin so, the rails console is a bit weird to me.

any help would really be appreciated
also using postgresql for the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have model `User` with attribute `admin` and you want to set the user with `id` 1 to admin true, in the Rails console you can do this:

```
User.find(1).update(admin: true)
```

`find` will return the instance corresponding to the `id` provided.

You can learn more about Active Record in [this Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html).

If you are going to need to do this more than once, you might consider using Rails database seeding described [here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html).

Comment: thanks for that! does this also work with the heroku console? and postgresql?

Comment: Yes and yes.  I believe you would use `heroku run rails console` to run the Rails console on a Heroku server.